# Auto Create FormControls from elements in Reactive Forms Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

As you know when we create forms with Reactive Forms in Angular we assign formcontrolname to elements and also manually create formcontrols like below:

```
<form   [formGroup]="ntForm" (change)="onChange($event)" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="nt-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input  matInput placeholder="User Id" formControlName="userId" [min]="5">
    <mat-error >{{getErrors('userId')}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Id"  formControlName="id" required [min]="10">
    <mat-error >{{getErrors('id')}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Title" formControlName="title" [email]="true">
    <mat-error >{{getErrors('title')}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <button class="nt-form-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Manually adding formcontrols:

```
 this.ntForm = this.form.group({
      'id': new FormControl('id'),
      'userId': new FormControl('userId'),
      'title': new FormControl('title')   
    });
```

This may seems simple at first but what about if we have 20 elements?
We need to manually add names and maintain them. In Agile development it will be pain.
To solve this I create a function which auto create controls based on formControlName attribute:

```
 fillControls(data) {
    const els: any = document.getElementsByClassName('nt-form')[0]
      .querySelectorAll('[formControlName]');
    els.forEach(node => {
      const controlName = node.attributes['formcontrolname'].nodeValue;
      this.ntForm.addControl(controlName, new FormControl('', []));
    });
  }
```

But with this approach errors will be emitted stating ('Cannot find control with name: '') because I firstly initialize form with empty controls and them fill it. 
How can I solve this problem? thanks

Comment: why are you using document.getElementsByClassName in angular

Comment: Because I want to query elements of form with specified class only.

Comment: in angular you can select element using element ref

Comment: yes code can be optimized later but now it is needed to solve current problem.

Comment: do you want to create form with dynamic data?

Comment: yes but with agile approach.

Comment: Hey @VugarAbdullayev did you went any further with this? really like where this is going...
Was thinking about having an array of controls settings lets say.. 
{
title/controlName,
type (text/ number / boolean / etc),
required boolean,
source (in case its a select in type)

and see how to scaffold from there

Comment: Maybe this will be of help, you can take the concept and rework it so that it fits your needs : https://eliteionic.com/tutorials/creating-dynamic-angular-forms-with-json/#pass-json-data-into-the-component

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, you're doing it wrong.

Instead of getting the control names from HTML, you should get it from the TS and iterate over it from the HTML.

For instance, you could use an interface to create form controls, use a static method to create a form group from it, and iterate over the interfaced elements in your HTML.

```js
export interface ReactiveFormControl {
  name: string;
  placeholder: string;
  defaultValue: string;
  validators: Validators[];
}

export class ReactiveFormUtils {
  public static toFormGroup(builder: FormBuilder, controls: ReactiveFormControl[]) {
    const form = {};
    controls.forEach(control => form[control.name] = [control.defaultValue, [...control.validators]]);
    return builder.group(form);
  }

  public static getControlNames(controls: ReactiveFormControl[]) {
    return controls.map(control => control.name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks but how the elements in form will be binded to formGroup without formControlName?

Comment: They will have a form control name, you just have to iterate over it and use the name property

Comment: But with this solution I create names twice in html side and ts side. So it is like creating usual reactive form. Could you please provide sample? thanks

Comment: No you don't ... You simply use a loop in your HTML `<input type="text" *ngFor="let control of controls" [formControlName]="control.name">`.

Comment: but this will work only on same elements such as input. What if form is mix of inputs,selects ,checkboxes and so on with mixed order?

Comment: I was giving you a general idea, not the exact code to use ... And by the way, select, checkboxes, radio buttons, numbers, textareas, files and almost anything can be treated as a string. Furthermore, since JS doesn't type variables, this code will work.